# Need help identifying a radial aircraft engine

Tags: aircraft-identification, engine, piston-engine

I work at the Naval Air Station Wildwood Aviation Museum in Rio Grande NJ.  We just acquired what we believe to be a radial aircraft engine that was found by fisherman in the Atlantic Ocean.  We'd like to display it, but need to identify it first.  Any help would be great. It is an 18 cylinder engine.  We have R-2800 double wasp engine 18 cylinder engine on display that is much larger then the engine we are trying to identify. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Bristol Taurus, Pratt & Whitney R-1830, R-2000, and Wright R-2600 are twin-row 14-cylinder engines.

Could you estimate the overall diameter of the engine?  You can readily measure the bore -- that would be helpful.

The bore of the Taurus is 5", R-1830 is 5.5", the R-2000 is 5.75", the R-2600 is 6.125"

18-cylinder radial engines include:

Pratt & Whitney R-1535.  5.1875" Bore, 44" diameter

Pratt & Whitney R-2800.  5.75" Bore, 53" diameter

Wright R-3350. 6.125" Bore, 55.7" diameter

Comment: Thanks for the quick response  The cylinder diameter is approx. 5.75"  I counted the cylinders again and there are 18.

Comment: Taurus is out, being a sleeve valve. Sounds like R2800 is it. You could probably confirm it by finding an image from an R2800 parts or repair manual that shows the gear train on the accessory cover.